# how make change event Listener works even when it wont changes

Tags: javascript, onchange, event-listener

I want to show some randomly dog pics when somebody clicks on dropdown menu items(with different breed items). But if I use change event, and I wanna see more pics of specific breed for multiple time, it wont work. so how should I handle that ?
[dogApp](https://amir-haghighi.github.io/dogapp) 
[dogApp codes](https://github.com/amir-haghighi/dogapp)

```
 const select = document.querySelector(".breeds")
select.addEventListener("change", event =>{
    breed = event.target.value ;
        fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
        .then(response=>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data=>{   
            img.src = data.message
         })
})
```

Comment: could you add more explanation with your dropdown html

Comment: Hi, you can use click. Change event is fired if it's changed, but in your case you don't need  it.

Comment: @Joseph https://github.com/amir-haghighi/dogapp

Comment: @Joseph https://amir-haghighi.github.io/dogapp/

Comment: @IvanGanchev tnx . but have u ever used click event for select tag ?!!! it will fire whenever touch the menu ! literally it wont work ! how should i use that to work

Comment: Hi, here we try to help each other so question like "have u ever used click event for select tag ?!!! " is not productive. I'm trying to understand use case to provide some advice how to solve the problem. [See this](https://codepen.io/iganchev87/pen/abBOZOQ)  it will call alert only if click on some of the options. I see that you add comment on @Stanislas answer  "but if i delete the select.value". What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

`change` handlers will only trigger when the value of the `select` element changes. Since you're re-selecting the same value, the value doesn't change, meaning the event does not trigger.

Some options to solve this:

- Clear the content of the select after an item has been selected.
- Add more event listeners, you'll likely need `focus`, `click` and `keypress`
- Take a different more logical approach to the UI, as this is not what selects are supposed to do.

Comment: tnx for your answer , but if i delete the select.value , it will show nothing on the menu , (i want to show the "breed name " ) and if i should use more event listener , how ?!

Comment: @amirhosein_20 If you clear the `select`, you could just add a header (like `h1`) right below the `select` with the breed of the displayed dog. Or you could just drop the `select` entirely and implement your own dropdown using styled `div` or `ul` and `li` tags.